# Terminating an application while the Spring state machine is running

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

The Spring state machine is configured as follows, for example:

A (initial) --> B --> C (choice) --> D/E/F --> G (end)


The states B,D,E,F take a long time to execute.

When the application terminates, the state machine executes the current state and stops, without any errors.


For example, if state machine stops when state B action executed, then state machine will have current state B and no information about the D/E/F states that I could use to continue execution of the state machine with another app.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/354#issuecomment-299121905